# React Native - undefined is not an object (evaluating '_get2.queue')

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga, react-native-community-netinfo, redux-offline

I'm trying to find a way to know when a user is connected and when he disconnects, so that when he disconnects, I save his actions offline and when he connects again, I send them to the server.
I'm using Redux Saga, Redux Offline Queue and Netinfo to do it, but I'm not being able to figure it out.

```
import {put, take} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {eventChannel} from 'redux-saga';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import {OFFLINE, ONLINE} from 'redux-offline-queue';

export function* startWatchingNetworkConnectivity() {
  const channel = eventChannel((emitter) => {
    NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      emitter(state.isConnected);
    });

    return () => console.log('Test');
  });

  try {
    while (true) {
      const isConnected = yield take(channel);

      if (isConnected) {
        yield put({type: ONLINE});
      } else {
        yield put({type: OFFLINE});
      }
    }
  } finally {
    channel.close();
  }
}
```

I know that the eventChannel must return a function to unsubscribe, but I want it to never stop while the App is active, so I returned a console.log() just to test. I don't know if the return is the issue, or something else.
I'm not able to fire those ONLINE and OFFLINE actions, can someone help me please?

Comment: Is callback inside `NetInfo.addEventListener` actually invoked? Is `state` variable undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Changing getState() to getOffline().toObject() inside offlineMiddleware.js solved the issue for me.